# What is the best way to remove/skip an item from collection

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is the best way to remove/skip an item from collection object

```
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>()
personList  = dao.GetData(123);
personList = personList.Select(x => x.Comment... ????
```

resultset:

```
"GCE"   
Not available 
""               //comments
"RES" 
9.97000000 
9.99000000 

........
........
........
```

so, i am targeting the field called "comments" and if the comments are empty then dont render.

i could have do that in `foreach` loop with an `if condition` but i am looking for the best practice

Comment: Look into the `Where` extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will restrict the list to comments that have a non-null and non-whitespace string:

```
List<Person> personList = dao.GetData(123); 
filteredList = personList.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(x.Comment));
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to *destructively* remove the offending item from the list then use the `RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)` method; it removes every item that matches a predicate from the list:

```
myList.RemoveAll(x=>x.Comment == whatever);
```

If you want to keep the list the same and make a *filtered sequence* of items then use `Where`:

```
foreach(Item item in myList.Where(x=>x.Comment != whatever))
    ...
```

That keeps the list the same; the `Where` just gives you a "view" of the list that has the filter applied to it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Where` like...

```
foreach (var a in personList.where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(x.Comment))
{
   // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to filter the collection before you even use it.  For starters, this is kind of redundant:

```
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>()
personList  = dao.GetData(123);
personList = personList.Select(x => x.Comment... ????
```

It sounds like what you're looking for is this:

```
var personList = dao.GetData(123)
                    .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(p.Comment))
                    .Select(p => ...
```

Then you can loop through the items in `personList`.

Of course, looking back, if you don't even *need* the `.Select()` (that is, if it's not doing anything other than an attempt to filter), then this is simpler:

```
var personList = dao.GetData(123)
                    .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(p.Comment))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two extensions you could care about:

`Where`:

```
var subset = collection.Where(x => x != someValue);
```

This method simply takes all the elements and applies the predicate to it, yielding only the matching elements.

And `Skip`, `SkipWhile`:

```
var skipFirstThreeItems = collection.Skip(3);
var skippedItems = collection.SkipWhile(x => x != "SomeValue")
```

The important distinction with the second one is that it will skip values until the predicate is matched, and then it will take all subsequent elements.

Answer (score 0):

I often think that the *best* way is debatable, but I like to be *explicit* about what the code is doing:

```
var peopleWithComments = dao.GetData(123)
  .Where(person => person.Comment.IsPresent());

...

public static class StringExtensions {
  public bool IsPresent(this string self) {
    return !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(self);
  }
}
```